# R: Combine duplicate columns after dplyr join

Tags: r, dplyr

When you use a dplyr `join` function like `full_join`, columns with identical names are duplicated and given suffixes like "col.x", "col.y", "col.x.x", etc. when they are not used to join the tables.

```
library(dplyr)
data1<-data.frame(
          Code=c(2,1,18,5), 
          Country=c("Canada", "USA", "Brazil", "Iran"), 
          x=c(50,29,40,29))
data2<-data.frame(
          Code=c(2,40,18),
          Country=c("Canada","Japan","Brazil"), 
          y=c(22,30,94))
data3<-data.frame(
          Code=c(25,14,52),
          Country=c("China","Japan","Australia"), 
          z=c(22,30,94))

data4<-Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by="Code"), list(data1,data2,data3))
```

This results in "Country", "Country.x", and "Country.y" columns.

Is there a way to combine the three columns into one, such that if a row has NA for a "Country", it takes the value from "Country.x" or "Country.y"?

I attempted a solution based on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110179/can-i-replace-nas-when-joining-two-data-frames-with-dplyr), but it gives me a warning and returns only values from the top three rows.

```
 data4<-Reduce(function(...) full_join(..., by="Code"), list(data1,data2,data3)) %>%
        mutate(Country=coalesce(Country.x,Country.y,Country)) %>%
        select(-Country.x, -Country.y)
```

This returns the warning `invalid factor level, NA generated`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can remove the `by=Code` to get your desired output. Then, it will join base on `Code` and `Country`. The warning is because the class of `Country` is `factor`. You can change it to `character` to prevent the error.

Comment: Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you create the data frame using `data.frame`, or you can use `data_frame` from the `dplyr` package to prevent columns to be `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), make a full join and deal with the conflicts using `dplyr::coalesce`.

First we'll have to rename the tables to have value columns named the same.

```
library(dplyr)
data1 <- rename_at(data1,3, ~"value")
data2 <- rename_at(data2,3, ~"value")
data3 <- rename_at(data3,3, ~"value")
```

Then we can join

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
data1 %>%
  safe_full_join(data2, by = c("Code","Country"), conflict = coalesce) %>%
  safe_full_join(data3, by = c("Code","Country"), conflict = coalesce)
#   Code   Country value
# 1    2    Canada    50
# 2    1       USA    29
# 3   18    Brazil    40
# 4    5      Iran    29
# 5   40     Japan    30
# 6   25     China    22
# 7   14     Japan    30
# 8   52 Australia    94
```

You get some warnings because you're joining factor columns with different levels, add parameter `check=""` to remove them.