# How to join two data frames without introducing NAs and duplicate columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, data-wrangling

My data frame has some missing values for certain variables. I have put together another data frame that has those missing values. When I try to combine them, it introduces NA values with duplicate columns. I have tried all four joins (left, right, full, inner, anti), but nothing is working. I'm missing some command in left_join, but not sure which one.How do I join these?

dat_nc <- left_join(dat_NC, dat_missing, by = c("year", "location", "spread_event"))

I am expecting to replace missing values with the values from another data frame.

Comment: As no data for the two datasets is available, I have to resort to guessing: are you sure, the columns you are joining by are actually structually the same (datatype etc.)?

Comment: I don't see any common columns between the 2 data frames.  How do they relate?  Assume row 1 from table 1 goes with row 1 of table 2?

Comment: `*_join` by itself will duplicate your columns rather than replacing the `NA` values. Have a look here for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110179/can-i-replace-nas-when-joining-two-data-frames-with-dplyr

Comment: @Dome42 yes, they are the same type. A few values in certain rows are missing. Column titles are same in both data sets.

Comment: @Dave2e location, year, and spread_event are in both data sets. I just wanted to show missing data that's why you can't see the whole data sets, which is rather large

Comment: If a row has NA for one of the key columns, what result do you want? Should it only appear in the output and be linked if if it NA in both tables? In that case you might convert the NA to "NA" so that it is not linked to all values. Where you are trying to "replace missing values from other data frame," are the available columns distinct enough to uniquely link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I replace NAs when joining two data frames with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110179/can-i-replace-nas-when-joining-two-data-frames-with-dplyr)

Comment: @JonSpring I'm trying to replace "replace missing values from other data frame,". Only column names are overlapping  - values are distinct.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: @JohnPolo Yes, thank you very much. I just needed to use distinct() function to get rid of duplicate rows after joining. If you could answer the question please, I will accept your answer to close the question. Please mentioned distinct() function in your answer too. Thanks again

Comment: @JohnPolo This was the full code used in the solution                                                     dat_nc <-
  left_join(dat_NC, dat_missing, by = c("year", "location", "spread_event")) %>%
  mutate(mean_ws = coalesce(mean_ws.x, mean_ws.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_ws.x, -mean_ws.y) %>%
  mutate(mean_temp = coalesce(mean_temp.x, mean_temp.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_temp.x, -mean_temp.y) %>%
  mutate(mean_rh = coalesce(mean_rh.x, mean_rh.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_rh.x, -mean_rh.y) %>%
  mutate(mean_wd = coalesce(mean_wd.x, mean_wd.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_wd.x, -mean_wd.y) %>%
  distinct()

Comment: If the code in the comment works, you can write the answer yourself. I don't feel like I should take code you wrote to write an answer that gives me credit. Don't forget to click "Accept" on the answer after you have written the answer.

Comment: I have answered the question. Stackoverflow will let me accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use coalesce() function after joining to "replace NA values with the data from the second data frame," and then distinct function to get rid of duplicate values introduced by coalesce() function.

```
dat_nc <-
  left_join(dat_NC, dat_missing, by = c("year", "location", "spread_event")) %>%
  mutate(mean_ws = coalesce(mean_ws.x, mean_ws.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_ws.x, -mean_ws.y) %>%
  mutate(mean_temp = coalesce(mean_temp.x, mean_temp.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_temp.x, -mean_temp.y) %>%
  mutate(mean_rh = coalesce(mean_rh.x, mean_rh.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_rh.x, -mean_rh.y) %>%
  mutate(mean_wd = coalesce(mean_wd.x, mean_wd.y)) %>%
  select(-mean_wd.x, -mean_wd.y) %>%
  mutate(lwd_duration = coalesce(lwd_duration.x, lwd_duration.y)) %>%
  select(-lwd_duration.x, -lwd_duration.y) %>%
  distinct()
```